# How to only get an associative array in MySQL results?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

issue:

```
$a = array("a" => "1", "b" => "2");
print_r($a);
```

output:

```
Array = ([0]=>'1'
         [a]=>'1'
         [1]=>'2'
         [b]=>'2')
```

but what I want is like

```
Array = ( [a]=>'1'
          [b]=>'2')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The output you get is quite interesting due to the syntax error you have.

Comment: sorry...It's a mistake.I've edited.But I want the output like the below.`Array = ( [a]=>'1'
          [b]=>'2')`

Comment: From the code provided in your question the result you are looking for will be given.

Comment: note that the quotes will not be shown in the output, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You're not by any chance retrieving this array using a mysql_fetch are you?

Comment: @josmith  I got this:`Array = ([0]=>'1'
         [a]=>'1'
         [1]=>'2'
         [b]=>'2')`  but I want this:`Array = ( [a]=>'1'
          [b]=>'2')`

Comment: Please answer Mark Baker's question.

Comment: @Mark Baker:Yes. I did a mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: @anna Your original question is a perfect example of the XY Problem (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ).  In the future, ask about your actual problem and not about your attempted solution.

Comment: @Crontab Sorry, I can't agree with you. I know what I got and what I want, but nothing about how to get what I want.

Comment: @anna I was just referring to the use of `mysql_fetch_array()`.  If you would've put that into your original question, I (and I'm sure a lot of other people) would have been able to give you an answer right away.  It never dawned on me that you were trying to extract data from a database because you explicitly stated it was from an array.

Comment: @Crontab I have to admit that. My friend has complained to me for the same reason. Thanks for your hints and patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [the manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

> By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both
>   associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get
>   associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM,
>   you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

Unless you tell mysql_fetch_array to return associative, then it will return both enumarated and associative entries for each column

specify MYSQL_ASSOC as the second argument to your mysql_fetch_array to fix this problem

In the longer term, I'd also recommend dropping mysql and using mysqli or even pdo

Comment: Great! I forgot this parameter...Thanks!

Comment: Was just about to answer! Anyway anna in the further please specify all details around the problem, this could be solved in like a minute if you specified that you populated the array from an database using mysql_fetch_array. So make sure you provide all details that is essential towards the problem.

Answer (score 5):

should be:

```
$a=array('a'=> '1','b'=> '2');
```

Or if you mean you want to display the array, then

```
$a=array('a'=> '1','b'=> '2');
$data = print_r($a, true);
echo $data;
//would result in
Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. This is a mistake..But I want the output like this.`Array = ( [a]=>'1' [b]=>'2')`

Comment: thats how it gets printed... isnt it

Comment: no, I got:`Array = ([0]=>'1'
         [a]=>'1'
         [1]=>'2'
         [b]=>'2')`, but I want:`Array('a'=> '1','b'=> '2')`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$a = array("a" => "1", "b" => "2");
```

instead of what you have.

Answer (score 1):

It should be: $a=array('a'=>'1','b'=> 2');

Answer (score 0):

```
//do this
$a = array("a" => "1", "b" => "2");
//or do this
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

`PDO:FETCH_ASSOC` is the equivalent of `MYSQL_ASSOC` for those using PDO.

i.e.,

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT...");
$a = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```